# How to check if website post title has certain word in it?

Tags: python

I'm building one bot for fun and I need some help.
I successfully made the part where my bot will automatically reply to comments if there is already a comment containing certain words in it. (I removed all bot info from the beginning including my account info)

```
import praw
import time

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id = "------------",
    client_secret = "-------------",
    user_agent = "replyBot",
    password = "---------",
    username = "-------")

subreddit = reddit.subreddit("all")


for submission in subreddit.new(limit = 10):
    print("****")
    print(submission.title)

    for comment in submission.comments:
        if hasattr(comment, "body"):
            comment_lower = comment.body.lower()
            if "certain word" in comment_lower:
                print("-------")
                print(submission.title)
                print(comment.body)
                print(comment.author)

                comment.reply("Test reply")
                time.sleep(780)
```

This code, once executed gives such output which is alright(I randomly put r/love so I can show you its output), in this case, it outputs post title, a comment which includes word "love" in it and author of that comment.

[image]

Now I can't figure out how to make bot to do the same thing(prints post title,comment and its author) but if there is certain word in the POST TITLE and not the comments section.

EDIT :
This is what I tried

```
for title_name in submission.title:
    if hasattr(title_name, "title"):
        title_lower = title_name.body.lower()
        if " love " in title_lower:
            print(submission.title)
```

Comment: You know how to extract the title (with `submission.title`), you know how to check whether a substring is contained in a string (with `if "certain word" in comment_lower:`), yet you somehow don't know how to check is the title contains a certain substring? I don't understand what the problem here is.

Comment: Somehow, yes. I don't understand why it won't work the same way. I tried many ways and same as comments but it won't work that way for title.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add what you have already tried?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: You seem to have trouble applying your techniques to a given problem.  This is suggests more practice in exercises and perhaps some work with a tutor or on-line challenge problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used Reddit SDK, but I suspect the issues with your code are the following:

1. `title` doesn't have a body.
2. You don't need to iterate through the submission's title, as there is only one for a given post.
3. The issue with checking if the string is contained in the title might be caused by the spaces in your string: your code is going to print the post only if the title contains something like *"I love ice-cream"*, but it won't print it for *"Love is a good thing"*.

Example:

```
for submission in subreddit.new(limit = 10):
    print("****")
    print(submission.title)
    
    title = submission.title
    if "love" in title.lower():
        print(f"Found 'love' in {title}")
```

You can find the documentation for the `praw` package [here](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/submission.html).